# error function return in c

Tags: c, function, char, return

I need recive the char* from a function but I don't understand what is wrong.

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

    char *respuesta;
    respuesta = comunicacion(comando);
    printf("respuesta uno %s",respuesta);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char *comunicacion(char data[])
{
        unsigned char c ='d';
        char *respuesta;

        append(respuesta,c);

        return respuesta;
}
void append(char* s, char c)
{
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}
```

this is the error:
main.c:24:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: Show the source of `append` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see the "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" warning is that your `comunicacion` function lacks a prototype. When this happens, C assumes that your function returns an `int`, and all its parameters are `int` as well. Since neither of these is true about your `comunicacion` function, your code has undefined behavior.

Another problem is that `comando` is undefined. Finally, when you call `append`, `respuesta` is uninitialized. Using it in any way inside the `append` function would be undefined behavior, so the call `strlen` on the vale that's uninitialized is illegal.

Finally, note that the `data` parameter is unused in the `comunicacion` function. This needs to be changed - either use the parameter, or remove it from the function's signature.

Comment: I put this before the main funtion, char *comunicacion(char data[]); for the prototipe and compiled, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. in respuesta = comunicacion(comando); .... the compiler is assuming that comunicacion returns an int, since it has not seen a prototyp[e or definition. This is likely what generates the warning.
2. in main(), comando apparently has not been declared. Had it already been defined as a global variable?
3. in comunicacion(), respuesta is never set to anything. The call to append can have no effect on the value of respuesta.